# REST: Sending additional user data with some requests

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a REST service implemented using Spring. For some requests i'd like to transfer some additional data from client, like timestamp and username (and maybe something else) to keep some kind of actions log. What is the best and correct way to achieve that?

Obviously i could pass this data as a request params or within message body, but it would probably be wrong and will force me to update appropriate controllers - is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you do not want to change your controller's method signatures or not, but if you simply add HttpServletRequest into the parameters of your controller, spring will automatically inject this object.  It comes with all the metadata you are looking for including date/timestamp, username, etc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but i'm not sure if it's worth injecting a request. I just hope there's more elegant approach. But still, thanks for the reply

Comment: Check out this example for the HandlerInterceptorAdaptor.  It will handle cross-cutting concerns like audit/access logging of http requests

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/

it is an old example but interceptors are still there